# Email Diferenciando dois ambientes no sistema

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Pessoal Preciso de uma ajuda, no meu sistema eu tenho dois Ambientes, sendo um de produção e outro de homologação.
Sendo assim no meu sistema, eu tenho uma parte que envia e-mail, para o usuário.
Alguém poderia me ajudar para que na hora de enviar o email, o sistema idenficiar o ambiente e sinalizar com o nome [HOMOLOGAÇÃO] - [PRODUÇÃO]
Vou postar abaixo meu controller.

```
public void EnviaAlertaBaixoEstoque(Centro hospital, int tipo)
        {
            var fluidos = new List<string> { "", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
            var objEmail = FactoryMailMessage(MailPriority.High);

            objEmail.To.Add("Leonardo Macedo <exemplo@exemplo.com>");

            objEmail.Subject = $"Controle de Fluídos BaSICS - Aviso de estoque mínimo de fluídos {fluidos[tipo]} no {hospital.CentroId} - {hospital.Nome}";
            var fluido = hospital.EstoqueA;

            switch (tipo)
            {
                case 2:
                    fluido = hospital.EstoqueB;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    fluido = hospital.EstoqueC;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    fluido = hospital.EstoqueD;
                    break;

                case 5:
                    fluido = hospital.EstoqueE;
                    break;

                case 6:
                    fluido = hospital.EstoqueF;
                    break;
            }

            objEmail.Body = $"O {hospital.CentroId} - {hospital.Nome} está com estoque de fluídos {fluidos[tipo]} em {fluido} litro(s).";
            EnviarEmail(objEmail);
        }
```

Resumindo na mensagem **Controle de Fluídos BaSICS** antes da palavra **Controle** aparecer **[HOMOLOGAÇÃO]** Controle de Fluídos BaSICS ou **[PRODUÇÃO]** Controle de Fluídos BaSICS 
Achei um exemplo na internet só que não consegui implementar no meu sistema.

```
var titulo = "zzzz";
if (Request.Url.Scheme.Contains("homolog"))
{
 titulo = "[HOMOLOGAÇÃO] " + titulo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução que costumo ver para esse tipo de problema é colocar uma key no `web.config`.

`<appSettings>
    <add key="ambiente" value="HOMOLOGAÇÃO" />
    ...
</appSettings>`

Depois você pega e usa como quiser:

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ambiente"]`

No `web.config` você tem flexibilidade para alterar a variável sem precisar de DLL e existem formas de sincronizar com produção como `Web.Debug.config` e `Web.Release.config`

**ATUALIZANDO**

O `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ambiente"]` retorna o valor da `key`ambiente que está no `web.config`, então no ambiente de homologação essa key até um valor, no de produção outro valor.

Você vai pegar o valor dela assim:

`var amb = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ambiente"]`

A variável `amb` terá o valor que a `key` ambiente tem no `web.config`, a partir daí você pode implementar a regra que você achar melhor.

Comment: eu meio que entendi, poderia me explicar novamente em como uso System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ambiente"], aonde usar

Comment: atualizei a resposta, vê se deu para entender legal agora.

Answer (score 2):

A melhor opção para você resolver seu problema é trabalhar com Transformações Web Config, ou seja, você terá um arquivo Web.Config -> Web.Producao.config -> Web.Homologacao.config.

Antes de qualquer coisa, precisamos criar duas novas configurações: HOMOLOGACAO e PRODUCAO da seguinte maneira:

- Clique em Build -> Configuration Manager
- Clique em New
- Adicione o Name (Homologacao) e selecione Copy Settings from para Empty e clique em OK
- Agora temos que criar o Web.Config para nossa nova configuração, clique com o botão direito sobre Web.Config da aplicação e selecione Add Config Transform
- Automaticamente será criado um novo arquivo Web.Homologacao.Config

Repita o mesmo processo acima para criar o ambiente de PRODUCAO.

Dessa forma, conseguimos criar um web.config para cada ambiente que estiver trabalhando, tudo isso de forma automática.

Dentro do arquivo Web.config você cria uma seção para incluir parâmetros globais que podem ser utilizados no seu sistema, ex:

Web.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Ambiente" value="DESENVOLVIMENTO" />
  </appSettings>
```

Quando você fizer o Deploy / Publish da sua aplicação, teoricamente você irá definir o modo em que irá fazer a operação no seu caso teremos HOMOLOGACAO e PRODUCAO. Automaticamente quando você fizer isso, o arquivo Web.config  terá os parametros alterados conforme nossos arquivos Web.Producao.config ou Web.Homologacao.config, Ex.:

Web.Producao.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Ambiente" value="PRODUCAO"  xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>    
  </appSettings> 
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Web.Homologacao.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Ambiente" value="HOMOLOGACAO"  xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>    
  </appSettings> 
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Dentro do seu código, você irá chamado o ambiente da seguinte maneira:

```
 titulo = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ambiente"] + titulo;
```

Dessa forma você terá um Web.config para cada ambiente com os seus parâmetros específicos.

Segue um site de exemplo para você seguir:
http://www.leandroprado.com.br/2012/03/como-configurar-web-config-transform/

Comment: No if que mencionei no tópico o Request da um erro 'The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Você está chamando o Request em qual arquivo?

Comment: Basics.Project\Basics.Infra\Email.cs

Comment: O projeto que você está chamando é uma ClassLibrary? Caso positivo você vai receber este erro mesmo uma vz que você não está em nenhum contexto web para obter o valor do Request!